# Date Formats in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

```
((SELECT ES.MCH_POS
           FROM IFSAPP.EQUIPMENT_SERIAL ES
          WHERE ES.CONTRACT = W.CONTRACT
            AND ES.MCH_CODE = W.MCH_CODE), 'yyyy/mm/dd') as SALE_DATE
```

When I run this code an error is occurred as `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: is it only a prt of a Statement or the whole Statement?

Comment: @Chamara:This looks like part of a larger SQL statement. Please post the entire SQL code to diagnose more accurately!

Comment: It is a part of Statement.

Comment: So show the whole statement. The part you are showing seems to be in the select clause, and if it's preceded by `TO_CHAR` or `TO_DATE` there is nothing wrong with it syntactically. Without seeing the whole statement, we cannot help you. Doesn't Oracle tell you in which line of the statement the error occurs?

Comment: The SQL is too long. The error is appeared in fourth line. In the comma.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

This is a syntax error. Occasionally it really does mean we have a unpaired left parenthesis. More often it means we have made a bloomer, and we have a keyword or expression where the compiler expected a closing `)`. Sometimes it just points to a typo.

`, 'yyyy/mm/dd'` is a format mask, used in casting a string to a date or a date to string. However, your snippet has no TO_DATE() or TO_CHAR() function, so I'm guessing that's your problem. You have a format mask where the compiler thinks there should be just a `)`.

With just a subquery to go on it's hard to be sure but probably what you want is something like this:

```
(SELECT to_char(ES.MCH_POS, 'yyyy/mm/dd') as SALE_DATE
       FROM IFSAPP.EQUIPMENT_SERIAL ES
      WHERE ES.CONTRACT = W.CONTRACT
        AND ES.MCH_CODE = W.MCH_CODE)
```

---

If this is not the exact solution you require and doesn't help you get to it please **edit your question** to include more details regarding the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you need the `to_char()` function

```
TO_CHAR(date-value,'date-format-mask')
```

From your code snippet it should look more along these lines 9I think):

```
select ....
, to_char((SELECT ES.MCH_POS
           FROM IFSAPP.EQUIPMENT_SERIAL ES
          WHERE ES.CONTRACT = W.CONTRACT
            AND ES.MCH_CODE = W.MCH_CODE
            AND rownum = 1), 'yyyy/mm/dd') as SALE_DATE
```

i.e. the correlated subquery returns one date value, and that date value is then formatted as yyyy/mm/dd

nb: I threw in the `and rownum = 1` because as you see it above, that correlated subquery MUST only return a single date value.